# Why my java -version is different than what I see in mvn --version

Tags: java, maven, version

When I type

java -version in C:\ I see java version "1.7.0_05"

When I type

mvn --version I see:

Java version : 1.6.0_37

So why is this difference?

Answer (score 3):

JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variable point to different java directories/installations?